# Why is self.navigationController NULL when pushed from UITabBarController subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, uinavigationcontroller

This is what I am doing. I have a `tabBarControllerOne` with 5 tabs. On clicking one of the tabs, I present a modal view controller, which has a navigationBar and a `TabBarControllerTwo` (with 3 tabs). These three tabs are the matter for concern here.

In the 5th Tab of `tabBarController` I show modalViewController as

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.nextTabView];
  //  navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;


navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

NSLog(@"Displauing the navcontroller before pushing %@", navController);

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

Here, `nextTabView` is a tabBarController with 3 tabs. The views work. In the views, if I try something like.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: someController animated:YES];


// nothing works.
```

If I NSLog, it displays `self.navigationController` as `(null)`

Can someone tell me why this is not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedding a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController` is not supported.  Apple has a careful hierarchy of container view controllers, and a `UITabBarController` must be the root of its view controller hierarchy.

Additionally, as Joe points out, your views don't belong to the navigation controller; they belong to the tab bar controller, so their `navigationController` property is not set.

Comment: +1 for  `they belong to the tab bar controller, so their navigationController property is not set.`    I am looking for ideas to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The modal view controller does not belong to a `UINavigationController` stack therefore the property is not set. You will want to use [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) to notify the creating controller when something is selected then that controller can properly push the next controller on to the stack.

[UIViewController Reference:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **Discussion** 
>   Only returns a navigation controller if the view controller
>   is in its stack. This property is nil if a navigation controller
>   cannot be found.